# Puzzling Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java

This question has been asked many times, and usually I know how to handle it. This time OpenJDK 16, Netbeans 13 and Gradle are puzzling me. Although I am convinced I am overriding the necessary method the compiler insists that I am not.

I am trying to extend [GHObject](https://github-api.kohsuke.org/apidocs/org/kohsuke/github/GHObject.html), even writing the method manually, although usually I use Netbeans' hints to implement the missing methods. Also removing the @override does not help.

This is what I came up with as a minimum example:

```
package settlers.installer.model;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.kohsuke.github.GHObject;

public class MyGHObject extends GHObject {

    @Override
    public URL getHtmlUrl() throws IOException {
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

and the compiler emits

```
error: MyGHObject is not abstract and does not override abstract method getHtmlUrl() in GHObject
public class MyGHObject extends GHObject {
       ^
```

To rule out problems in Netbeans and OpenJDK 16 I switched to running command-line Gradle and openJDK 19. No change.

What could be missing?

Comment: I can use GHObject (and the other classes) without a problems. The issue arises when I want to extend one. And no, when I tried adding the annotations to my class it did not work. Will give that a try...

Comment: Somehow I believe the Netbeans Cache is not important. After all it is a Gradle build, and running `./gradlew clean build`on command line produces the same error.

Comment: Yeah, annotations are not the issue. I've looked at some of the concrete classes in the github repository that extend the abstract class of interest, and they are all without annotations. They don't look different from your code, other than overriding many of the non-abstract methods. But of course, that shouldn't matter to the compiler.

Comment: I think that it's likely a NetBeans hiccough

Comment: Meanwhile I exited from Netbeans and am just on vi and gradle, and I switched to OpenJDK 19-ea. The error is still the same.

Comment: I could not find the root cause or an otherwise satisfactory answer to the question. 
Meanwhile I implemented a workaround that no longer requires subclassing GHObject.